# How to put a pre-existing sqlite file into <Application_Home>/Library/?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, ios-simulator

My app uses Core Data. I have run the app in the simulator which has successfully created and populated the corresponding sqlite file. I now want to get this pre-existing sqlite file on to an actual device and be part of my app. I have located the simulator generated sqlite file at /Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/identifier/Documents/myapp.sqlite and dragged it into Xcode. This has added it to my application bundle but not in an appropriate directory (with the consequence that the sqlite file can be read but not written to).

From reading about the file system I believe that the best place to put the sqlite file would be in a custom directory 'Database' under Application_Home/Library/. I don't seem to be able to do this within Xcode and despite searching I am unable to figure out how to do the following:

(1) Create a sub-directory called 'Database' in Application_Home/Library/ ?
(2) Transfer the sqlite file to my newly created 'Database' directory ?

**Many thanks to @Daij-Djan of his answer below.**

**One other question:** the path to the sqlite file will be used by the persistent store coordinator. Now depending on the size of the sqlite file it may take a while to copy or move. How can you ensure that the example code provided by @Daij-Djan has executed and finished before the persistent store coordinator tries to reference the sqlite file?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

mock code

in appDidFinishLaunching.. maybe

```
dbpath = PATH_YOU_WANT
if(!file.exists_at:dbpath) {
    copy(dbinbundle, dbpath);
}
```

in objC:
(written inline, chance of typos/mistakes)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    NSString *lib = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbs = [lib stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database"];
    NSString *file = [dbs stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file]) {

        id dbInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"];

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dbs withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbInBundle toPath:file error:nil];
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: If the OP does not know how to create a subdirectory in `Library` and how to copy a default database there, then this pseudo-code will probably not help.

Comment: hey all! thanks so much for this. i am new to iOS. i had started looking into it from the pseudo code added. I thought I could do it in Xcode and didn't realise it had to be done programmatically. One other thing: the path to the sqlite file will be used by the persistent store coordinator. Now depending on the size of the sqlite file it may take a while to copy or move. How can you ensure that the above example code has executed and finished before the persistent store coordinator tries to reference the sqlite file?

Comment: do it before adding the Store to the PST. -> put the code before the code that loads the PST

Comment: i get that. what i am not sure of is: does the code execution wait until the call to copyItemAtPath has completed successfully before executing any more code? if not and the sqlite file was large then i believe that it is conceivable that the call to add the store to the PST, even if it is made after the call to copyItemAtPAth, could still happen before the copy has fully completed. thanks.